# Why would an ASP.NET site become veeeeeery slow after the network connection dropped?

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 site published in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit. The pages are accessed over SSL

One of our testers has determined that if, during a postback, he blocks network access on his PC, and then after a few seconds reconnects, our site becomes excruciatingly slow. Like 30 seconds per page load.

If he hits the refresh button in his browser it stays slow. If he closes the tab, then re-opens it, it becomes fast again.

This behavior happens with both IE 8 and the latest firefox. There are no event log entries on the server when this happens

My question:
- Has anyone seen this same behavior?
- Does anyone have a theory as to what causes it?

Comment: add Trace=True to your page, and see if you can narrow down which part slows down to a crawl.

Comment: Are you using SQL server as well? Could the issue be database related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but it might be related to HTTP keepalive. Try disabling that on the server and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. That makes good sense. I will try it and feed back

Answer (score 0):

I noticed same thing. I removed the cache and speed was fine again. Remove cache It may be causing problem.